# D3.js - Pie Layout - Add others attr from json

Tags: d3.js

i'm noob using D3 and complex json with this library and i have a problem, i need add another attr or images in each path of the pie chart and i don't know how

My json code:

```
    [
    {"hash_chart_name" : "Chart_1", "articles" : 25, "images" : 25, "videos" : 50, "hash_link" : "pepe_1"},
    {"hash_chart_name" : "Chart_2", "articles" : 25, "images" : 50, "videos" : 25, "hash_link" : "pepe_2"},
    {"hash_chart_name" : "Chart_3", "articles" : 50, "images" : 25, "videos" : 25, "hash_link" : "pepe_3"},
    {"hash_chart_name" : "Chart_4", "articles" : 75, "images" : 5, "videos" : 10, "hash_link" : "pepe_4"},
    {"hash_chart_name" : "Chart_5", "articles" : 10, "images" : 80, "videos" : 10, "hash_link" : "pepe_5"}
]
```

D3 Code:

```
    var radius = 90;

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range([chart_vars_object.color_1, chart_vars_object.color_2, chart_vars_object.color_3]);

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius)
        .innerRadius(radius - 50);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d) { return d.hash_taggeds_porcent; });

    d3.json("json_hard_coded.json", function(error, data) {
        color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "hash_chart_name"; }));



        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.hash_taggeds = color.domain().map(function(name) {
                //console.log({hash_taggeds_name: name, hash_taggeds_porcent: +d[name]});
                return {hash_taggeds_name: name, hash_taggeds_porcent: +d[name]};
            });
        });

        var svg = d3.select("#canvas_svg").selectAll(".pie")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("svg")
            .attr("class", "pie")
            .attr("width", radius * 2.5)
            .attr("height", radius * 2.5)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

        svg.selectAll(".arc")
            .data(function(d) { return pie(d.hash_taggeds); })
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", "arc")
            .attr("d", arc)
            //.attr("hash_link", function(d) { return d.hash_link;});
            .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.hash_taggeds_name); })
            .style({ 'stroke': 'Black', 'stroke-width': '5px'})
            .on("mouseover", function() {
                d3.select(this)
                    .classed("active", true )
            })
            .on("mouseout",  function() {
                d3.select(this)
                    .classed("active", false)
            });

        svg.append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style({"text-anchor":"middle", "color":"white"})
            .text(function(d) { return d.hash_chart_name; });

    });
```

well the attr :

```
.attr("hash_link", function(d) { return d.hash_link;});
```

don't work

How can i do?

Sorry for my english,  Thanks.-

Comment: What do you want the additional attribute to achieve? You can set anything you like as an attribute, but it won't have any effect in most of the cases.

Comment: I want to add attributes for access when on click.

Example:

I have 6 pie charts with 3 values and when i click on one path of the 6 pies than can open some information


like this site: http://social.ufc.com/

Comment: For this you would need either an on click handler and not an attribute or use the SVG anchor element -- see http://www.w3.org/wiki/SVG_Links

Comment: I need acces to: .attr("hash_link", function(d) { return d.hash_link;}); in path

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Lars's comment that you shouldn't need to store this property in an attribute since it will be available to you in the bound data. You should be able to access it in your click handler like this:

```
selection.on("click", function(el) {
    console.log(el.data.hash_link);
});
```

That said, in order for this to work you need to make this property available in your bound data. Since you're binding to `d.hashed_tags`, you'll want to make this property available on that object:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.hash_taggeds = color.domain().map(function(name) {
        return {hash_taggeds_name: name, hash_taggeds_porcent: +d[name], hash_link: d.hash_link};
    });
});
```